# input's enterKeyHint prop doesnt work on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, webview, next.js13

Im trying to display the blue "search" button on the keyboard when i focus an input but it doesnt work.
[image: keyboard search layout]

Im calling my nextJS page from a react-native webview, Here are the components.

Do you guys know what am I missing?

Input Component:

```html
<InputSearch
        ref={inputRefReceived}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        disabled={isInputDisabled()}
        searchOpen={searchOpen}
        inputMode="search"
        type="search"
        enterKeyHint="search"
        id="search-input"
        onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
      />
```

Input Styled-Component:

```css
export const InputSearch = styled.input<inputSearchProps>`
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  ${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.nunito[Variants.Medium]}
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.nunito[Variants.XLarge].fontSize};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.neutrals[100]};
  outline: none;
  display: ${props => (props.searchOpen ? 'initial' : 'none')};
  width: ${props => (props.searchOpen ? '100%;' : '0')};
`;
```

Webview:

```html
<WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          source={{
            uri: validateRoute(directions, idItem, warehouseId),
          }}
          textZoom={100}
          overScrollMode="never"
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
          onError={syntheticEvent => handleError(syntheticEvent)}
          allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={true}
          onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoadingWebView(false)}
          onLoadStart={() => setIsLoadingWebView(true)}
          onMessage={event => onMessage(event.nativeEvent.data)}
        />
```